# Java splitting string by custom regex match

Tags: java, regex, split

I am completely new to regular expressions so I'm looking for a bit of help here.

I am compiling under JDK 1.5

Take this line as an example that I read from standard input:

```
ab:Some string po:bubblegum
```

What I would like to do is split by the two characters and colon. That is, once the line is split and put into a string array, these should be the terms:

```
ab:Some string
po:bubblegum
```

I have this regex right now:

```
String[] split = input.split("[..:]");
```

This splits *at* the semicolon; what I would like is for it to match two characters and a semicolon, but split at the space before that starts. Is this even possible?

Here is the output from the string array:

```
ab
Some String po
bubblegum
```

I've read about Pattern.compile() as well. Is this something I should be considering?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
input.split(" (?=[A-Za-z]{2}:)")
```

The ?= creates a [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).  This means the engine looks ahead to see if the next part matches, without consuming that part.  If it does match, it splits on the space character.  `[A-Za-z]` means a upper or lower-case letter, while `{2}` specifies we want two characters matching that class.

Comment: Man that was fast—it works great. Thanks a bunch. Would it be possible for you to explain how it is working? I can understand that it is looking for two upper- or lower-case characters and then a colon but thats it.

Excellent, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You asked about [`Pattern#compile(String pattern)`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#compile(java.lang.String)). You should consider using it if you are going to use the regex a lot since the aforementioned method compiles the regex into something that's fast to execute while using [`String#split(String regex)`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) directly always recompiles the regex.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I just implemented it with the regex from Matthew and it still works.